# How can I see the total length of all the videos in a YouTube playlist?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

If I recall correctly, there used to be a feature of YouTube which showed the total length of all the videos in a playlist, combined. This was very useful as it enabled you to see the length of a game play-through, etc. A Google search suggests this feature has been removed and no immediate solution presents itself, but **is there a way to view the total length without having to add it up manually?**

Answer (score 18):

I made an app to do exactly that, hosted on Heroku: [YouTube Playlist Length](https://ytplaylist-len.sharats.dev/). You can also find the app repository [here](https://github.com/sharatsachin/ytplaylist-len).

*Note:* it can find the total length of a playlist that has up to 500 videos. If it has more than 500 videos, it shows the total length of the first 500 videos.

Comment: Curious why the limit up to 500 videos only.

Comment: @YetAnotherBot Google only lets you do a limited number of requests per day. If I remove the limit, the requests would get exceeded every day. But if you want more, you can run the code with your own API key.

Answer (score 9):

since RedDragon's web tool returneed me an "Internal Server Error" and apparently is not maintained I made a quick few-liner that returns duration, which you can paste into devtools:

```
var minutes = [... document.querySelectorAll("ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer > span")]
.reduce((acc, dur) => {
    dur = dur.textContent.trim().split(':');
            var durlen = dur.length;
        if (durlen > 2) {
            return acc + parseInt(dur[0]) * 3600 + parseInt(dur[1]) * 60 + parseInt(dur[2]);
        } else {
            return acc + parseInt(dur[0]) * 60 + parseInt(dur[1]);
        }
      }, 0) / 60;
    alert(Math.floor(minutes / (60 * 24)) + " days " + Math.floor((minutes / 60) % 24) + " hours " + Math.floor(minutes % 60) + " minutes.");
```

or instead of pasting code into devtools you can install and use a userscript I just made, which runs the code above when you press alt + shift + u on a playlist page.

https://openuserjs.org/scripts/Wis/YouTube_playlist_duration

Comment: I just used @RedDragon's web tool and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Nice for Firefox-users

Answer (score 1):

You can try [YouTube Playlist Duration](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-playlist-duration/ijppgifnllaehojnpbphigenojfjnhml) Chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

[Youtube Playlist Duration Calculator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-playlist-duration/pijbakhgmhhadeakaocjfockpndcpobk) was released January 2020.

I just tested it and it worked well.

Comment: Mar '21, I confirm it still works. Useful to do it on the Watch later playlist, which cannot be used on other webpages.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firefox, you can install this add-on [Youtube Playlist Duration and Progress Calculator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/doe-hoon-lee/) to get full duration and watched time (also shown as a progress bar).

It works great with huge playlists too.

You can also blur/shade out watched videos too.

[image: Add-on in use]

Answer (score 1):

Well first we need to know is to possible to find Find YouTube Playlist Length, then Answer is yes, we can find it, and there are actually two ways to find Find YouTube Playlist Length.

1st way:

1. Open Chrome browser in your Mobile/Desktop
2. Search [ytplaylist-len.us](https://ytplaylist-len.us/)
3. Copy the link of the playlist whose length you want to calculate.
4. Now paste the copied link in the search box of the tool
5. It will calculate the youtube playlist length in no time.

2nd Way:

You can find with extension

1. Download [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-playlist-duration/pijbakhgmhhadeakaocjfockpndcpobk?hl=en) extension from chrome
2. Open and enable this extension
3. Go to Any YouTube Playlist Overview Page
4. Here you will see the duration of the playlist under the playlist
   title

Answer (score -1):

You can go to https://ytexplore.com and enter the playlist ID or URL to see the total duration of the playlist. **It not only shows the playlist duration but also show several other important metrics like the number of the channels in that playlist, view count, channels having highest/lowest video in the playlist** and many more promising metrics.

This web app can also show the **total number of videos of a channel and its length** and also several other important video metrics.
If you don’t understand how to do it. [Watch the YouTube video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaWn_EyBUIU)
[image]